# How to make red overlay screen Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, overlay

How  do I create a blinking red overlay over the layout screen in my android application

PS: I want to make an warning alert visualization

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `imageView` that has a red colored background and that spans over your entire layout.

To make it blink, you can use a `Timer` in Android that switches the opacity of the `imageView` between 0 and 1 with each timeUnit, say 0.5 seconds.

Comment: Hi Parth, can you explain how I could do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a background Image and you can change it in every 500ms by using timer task. That will make you feel like blinking else you can increase and decrease their optacity in some fixed time of interval.

Comment: Can you provide a code example of using the Timer and changing the color of ImageView Rahul?

Answer (score 0):

Put a ImageView, so you can switch android:background between red (0xffff0000) and transparent (0x00000000) using a Timer.

Comment: How'd I do that using a Timer?

Comment: Just google. By example:
https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/activity/android-timertask-example/ So, in your trigger use startTimer(). Then on run() change the background.

Comment: Hi Matias, what code would you do to switch between red and transparent?